# TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'vue__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__["default"].component')

Tags: javascript, vue.js, module, typeerror, vuejs3

I'm getting the error at Vue.component. I've tried searching the web and couldn't find any working fixes on SO or google.

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import Index from './Index.vue'
import Login from './Login.vue'

Vue.component(`index`, Index);
Vue.use(VueRouter)

const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  routes: [
    { path: '/', component: Login },
  ]
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router: router,
  render: h => h(Router)
})
```

Comment: you tagged your question with vuejs3 but the syntax is of version 2

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim do you know the correct v2 syntax?

Comment: the above syntax is for vue 2, which version are you currently using?

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim v3; my code is working now